# Why glReadPixels give missaligned result on some older android devices?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, glreadpixels

I have an app that works perfectly on many devices, I have a couple of users that reported app is not saving images properly.  The comman thing about the devices with problem is, they all are very old devices. Most likely they all use armeabi as their CPU_ABI.

Here is an example image from a user.
[image: Here is an example from a user.]

Comment: Unfortunately might just be a driver bug that you cant do anything about

Comment: Although I encourage you to explore this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8324489/1081340